# IOError: [Errno 0] Error when running python code using visual studio code

Tags: python, python-2.7, visual-studio-code

I'm very new to Visual Studio Code even beginner in python coding. I have tried the following very simple code:

```
for i in range(1000):
    print i
```

Each time I run the code I got the following error after printing some of i's:

```
print i
```

> IOError: [Errno 0] Error

I'm using python `2.7`

Your help on this is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure VS Code is set up to use python 2.7?

Comment: yes ! and I got the output for certain value of i then exit running with the above error

Answer (score 1):

After researching on the web about it, it appears to be a Windows issue which has been resolved in the Windows 1803 release. See https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/36630#issuecomment-357084696

**Edit**:

A workaround is to use external instead of redirected terminal.

Add the line:

```
"console": "externalTerminal",
```

to your `launch.json`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a problem with input/output. Try to run it from cmd or bash if you are on Ubuntu.If that doesn't  work try from Python IDLE.

Comment: Im using windows 10 but I have run it using IDLE and it is working fine. I just got the error when I run it using VS Code only